# Find string A in file and print line with string A along with next lines till you match string B

Tags: python, loops, file

I have text file where I need to match specific string and print that line along with
next few lines till another string is found.

```
String A:  'MRATE'
Sting B:  'GRATE'
String C: 'URATE'
```

Texts from file:

```
AAAA
BBBB
MRATE >>>>> First occurrence of String A
TRATE
SRATE
GRATE
QRATE
MRATE >>>>> Second occurrence of String A
ZRATE
GRATE 
ZRATE
URATE
```

Here first code should match the first occurrence of `'MRATE'` and print following till `'GRATE'` is found:

```
MRATE
TRATE
SRATE
GRATE
```

Then it continue to match second occurrence of `'MRATE'` and print following till `'GRATE'` is found.  At this point it should exit out of the file.

Comment: what have you tried so far ??

Comment: Have you had an attempt at getting this to work? If so please share that code.
If not, take a look at reading from a file line by line (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp), look at printing results (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_intro.asp) and also look at putting some logic in place to satisfy your needs (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp).
It's amazing what can be done with a little practise :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.